# Panel changing the ownership?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, panel

In my C# application there is a main form with a panel `main_panel`. Whenever the user selects something in the menu, lets say "A", the main panel switches to the form A's panel (look at the code), `A_panel`.

Since `A_panel` covers every controls in form A, I can summon all of the controls of form A into main form.

```
if ((string)MainMenu.SelectedItem == "A")
{
    FormA A = new FormA();
    new_panel = A.Controls["A_panel"] as Panel;
}
this.main_panel.Controls.Clear();
this.main_panel.Controls.Add(new_panel);
```

My question is when user selects menu A again, I don't want to recreate `FormA` again by `new FormA()`. I did because when I add control to the `main_panel`, then the `A_panel`'s ownership changes to main form so that it was possible to add the control to `main_panel` again.

So, how to change the ownership of `A_panel` to Form A again?
And how to solve my problem generally?

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you can't use a `UserControl` and keep a reference to it on your form?  That way you can just show/hide it when the user wants to change views.  It would be much easier to extend and interact with.  [Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) a walk-through on MSDN to get you started.

Comment: But I am dealing with more than 5~6 menus at one time. So you mean that I have to put all of them in one form and modify it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a UserControl would suit your needs better. Have one instance on FormA and another on your MainForm.

If, for some reason, you can't use user controls, you could at least extract the code outside the autogenerated designer file (which I assume is why you're using FormA at all).

As in:

**FormA**

```
public FormA()
{
    var mainPanel = CreateMainPanel();
    this.Controls.Add(mainPanel)
}

public Panel CreateMainPanel()
{
    //...build up your control tree. Cut the code from the designer if necesssary
}
```

**MainForm**

```
FormA _A = new FormA();

public void HandleMainMenuClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    if ((string)MainMenu.SelectedItem == "A")
    {    
        new_panel = _A.CreateMainPanel();
    }
    this.main_panel.Controls.Clear();
    this.main_panel.Controls.Add(new_panel);    
}
```

Comment: But I am dealing with more than 5~6 menus at one time. So you mean that I have to put all of them in one form and modify it?

Comment: I don't really understand your question Lee. How does the number of menus relate to your original post?

Comment: No I mean, when I use user control instead